# Factorization of Characteristic Function

Tags: integration, general-topology, measure-theory, continuity, factoring

Let $X$ be an *open* subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and for any subset $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, let $\chi_A$ be the characteristic function of $X$, i.e.:
$$
\chi_X(x):= \begin{cases}
1 & : x \in A\\
0 & : x \not\in A.
\end{cases}
$$

Can $\chi_X$ be written as $\chi_{(\frac1{2},\infty)}\circ f$ where $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to (0,1)$ continuously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This puts the following conditions on $f$: if $x \in X$, then $\chi_X(x)=\chi_{(\frac1{2},\infty)}(f(x))=1$ which means that $f(x) > \frac12$, while $x \notin X$ implies $\chi_X(x)=\chi_{(\frac1{2},\infty)}(f(0))=0$, so $f(x) \le \frac12$. So $X=f^{-1}[(\frac12, \infty)]$ and so $X$ is open when $f$ is continuous. If $X$ is also closed, connectedness of $\Bbb R^n$ implies that this can only happen for $X=\emptyset$ or $X=\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Sorry I made a typo, I meant $X$ is open.  I accepted the answer since this is my mistake but I corrected the question

Comment: @James_T In that case you *can* do it, as open = functionally open in metric spaces.

Comment: What is functionally open?

Comment: @James_T That we can write it as $f^{-1}[O]$ for $O$ open in $\Bbb R$ and $f: X \to \Bbb R$ continuous.

Comment: So we can factor $f$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $(0,1)$ and then use $\chi_{(\frac1{2},\infty)}$?  Do you have a reference to this functionally open term?  I've never seen it before.

Comment: @James_T Yes, you can. It doesn't matter if you use $(0,1)$ or $\Bbb R$ as codomain.I think Engelking (general topology) uses functionally open. And some papers and Gilman and Jerrison do too. It's of interest in completely regular spaces (equivalently defined by the fact that all functionally open sets form a base). In a perfectly normal space all open sets are functionally open with an argument involving Tietze's theorem.

Comment: Thanks, Henno.  I found the corollary in Engelking and it helped perfectly!